# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Model with ID=62 for Model with ID=2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

> Couldn't find MetricLocationHelper with ID=62 for Metric::MetricDirector with ID=2

I have `has_and_belongs_to_many` association and my models are

```
class MetricLocationHelper < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_and_belongs_to_many :metric_metric_directors, class_name: "Metric::MetricDirector", association_foreign_key: "metric_metric_director_id"
end
```

and

```
class Metric::MetricDirector < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :metric_location_helpers, foreign_key: 'metric_metric_director_id'

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :metric_location_helpers, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

My third table columns are

- metric_metric_director_id
- metric_location_helper_id

And in controller

```
 def metric_director_params
   params.require(:metric_metric_director).permit(:name, :username, :region, metric_location_helpers_attributes: [:id, :_destroy])
end
```

I am facing an issue while updating and creating a record.

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Metric::MetricDirectorsController#update
>
> Couldn't find MetricLocationHelper with ID=62 for Metric::MetricDirector with ID=2

Updated Code

```
class Metric::MetricDirectorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_metric_director, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def new
  @metric_director = Metric::MetricDirector.new
  @locations = @metric_director.metric_location_helpers.build
end

def edit
  @locations = @metric_director.metric_location_helpers
end

def create
  @metric_director = Metric::MetricDirector.new(metric_director_params)

  if @metric_director.save
    redirect_to metric_metric_directors_path, notice: 'Director was successfully created.'
  else
    render :new
  end
end

def update  
  if @metric_director.update(metric_director_params)
  redirect_to metric_metric_directors_path, notice: 'Director was successfully updated.'
  else
    render :edit
  end
end


private

  def set_metric_director
    @metric_director = Metric::MetricDirector.find(params[:id])
  end


def metric_director_params
   params.require(:metric_metric_director).permit(:name, :username, :region, metric_location_helpers_attributes: [:id, :_destroy])

end
```

your help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Your problem is in your update / create method. Could you paste the full controller code including any finder methods here please.

Comment: @Mark I have updated

Comment: Glad to see that my comment with `association_foreign_key` has helped to you.

Comment: You're method set_metric_director is what is throwing the error, it is being called every time you hit the update action and it can not find a Metric:MetricDirector with an ID of the param you're sending through

Comment: Then what i suppose to do? Could you please bit explain